# Modify Android Application Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I was trying to understand how the Activity lifecycle is being managed! Is there someone who is firing all the events of the lifecycle? maybe ActivityManagerService?

How do I if I want to customize the activity lifecycle and add a new event to it? Any guidance on what kind of changes needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

The lifecycle is managed by the system and is "hardcoded". You could grab the Android sources, modify them and then install them on your device, to realize your idea.
Having said that, this won't guide you a long way as your device will very probably the only one out there with this special lifecycle event, so you won't be able to share any applications that use this new event. Unless you convince Google that this even is an absolut killer feature that they should add in future versions of Android.

Comment: Thanks. But my question was about "How to do it"! I do know that i could grab the sources and modify it! But if someone can help me in "how" to do it, would be great!

Comment: So grab the sources and get started, then ask here if you need specific help. Seems like you want someone else to do it for you.  Getting development/analysis done for you for free isn't really the purpose of this website.

Comment: @Poldie, in this big world I only want to check if someone has already tried this! No point re-inventing the wheel - as simple as that!